# How to purify a Puja room if you think it has become impure?

Tags: rituals, puja

I want to know the process of purifying puja room. I think it is called "sthana-suddhi". Can anyone detail me the process related to it (vidhi, mantras, mudras and so on) ?

Comment: Use Panchagavya, five cow urine and pour to the corner of houses using mango leaves after cleaning the complete idols taking bath. Offer panchagavya to all at home as theertha. This can help you, your body, mind and place to be cleaned

Comment: The process mentioned by @Hansiemithun is good. One can also use Sambrani or Loban and Guggulu and the fumes of it cleans negative energy. Refer: https://youtu.be/vvv107N_BQQ

Comment: See this https://youtu.be/w7eBRDSDZbA

Comment: The process is called punyavachanna ritual

Answer (score 1):

One performs Shuddhi (śuddhi) to remove Doshas. Dosha means an innate memory that is not conducive to certain activities. Doshas are present everywhere. Yoga talks about Doshas within us. Everything in creation is Memory. There is nothing that doesn't hold memory (Like Quantum information). So Shuddhi is of two types, one is cleanliness, to make it sterile. The second is for Sanctity, meaning holiness. So the question arises how to do both?

If it were in preparation of Yajna Vedi/Shala then we have a huge list of activities and the Vedic Brahmana section will give a list of various things needed as preparatory steps, like tilling the soil, placing stones and much more. In your case, you said "pooja room", which means it's a personal residential dwelling like a home or apartment. In which case, Tantric Agamas do. Tantric agamas are very specific about building temples and homes. The reason is they want Sanctity to be embedded in the process of consecration. For temples, they do it before construction and once in 10 years through Kumba. But for residence, you need to consecrate your home by doing Vastu Pooja.

Now if it's an existing home that you have purchased or rented with prior tenants then you don't know what they used that space for. Hence, the memory (dosha) carries it unknown to you. So, the first part Shuddhi is cleanliness which you can do yourself, mope it thoroughly if it's tile/wood, and wet-vacuum it if it's carpet. Although carpet is not at all suitable for pooja gruhas. The second step for Scantity is to consecrate it, how? Get a Purohit home, start with Vinayaka Homa if you can. Then perform a Rath which are rituals defined in various Kalpas of Puranas. You may not be able to get out all doshas in one attempt, but you can keep superimposing your own memory over the existing, ones by performing rituals that emit their own essence. If we visit these old stone and wood with brick, tiled roof homes where poojas are a daily routine, such places have an aroma and a feel to them, that is very hard to reproduce. That only happens over time. So get a consecrated item into your pooja room, not just pictures, actual consecrated items like a Gudi and Yantra. If it's your own house, bring a cow inside. Let her spend some time in the room. Even let her excrete if possible. Clean it up. Apply river soil to the floor and mop it. Sprinkle water from rivers like Ganga or water which was used in Rituals inside Kalasha (pots of water into which divinity is established). Keep doing it and in due time your place may become a cacoon for Spiritual Sadhana.

Source: Daily practice and Family lineage.

Comment: You should cite sources.